# RSA get wrong result when input 3 or more plaintext

Tags: c#

I'm working on a rsa implementation, this my encryption code :

```
  plain = plaintext.Text;
  char[] charValues = plain.ToCharArray();
  string temp = "", temp2 = "";
  foreach (char _eachChar in charValues)
  {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(_eachChar);
        temp += String.Format("{0:X}", value); 
  }

  temp2 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(temp, 16));
  M = Convert.ToInt64(temp2);
  nilai_p = Convert.ToInt64(p.Text);
  nilai_q = Convert.ToInt64(q.Text);
  nilai_d = Convert.ToInt64(d.Text);
  nilai_n = nilai_p * nilai_q;
  nilai_delta_n = (nilai_p - 1) * (nilai_q - 1);
  long atas, tengah1 = a, tengah2 = b, bawah1 = 0, bawah2 = 1, temp;
  for (int i = 0; i <= b; i++)
  {
     atas = tengah1 / tengah2;
     temp = tengah1 - (tengah2 * atas);
     tengah1 = tengah2;
     tengah2 = temp;
     temp = bawah1 - (bawah2 * atas);
     bawah1 = bawah2;
     bawah2 = temp;
     if (tengah2 == 0)
         break;
  }
  if (bawah1 < 0)
       nilai_e = bawah1 + nilai_delta_n;
  else
        nilai_e = bawah1;
  BigInteger hasil = 0;
  hasil = BigInteger.ModPow(M, nilai_e, nilai_n);
```

and this my decryption code :

```
nilai_c = Convert.ToInt64(chipertext.Text);
nilai_d = Convert.ToInt64(D.Text);
nilai_n = Convert.ToInt64(N.Text);
BigInteger hasil = 0;
hasil = BigInteger.ModPow(nilai_c, nilai_d, nilai_n);
```

if I did input with 1 or 2 plaintext, the result is true, binary from plaintext will get back. but if 3 or 4 plaintext, the result will false.

I think the problem is here :

> BigInteger.ModPow(M, nilai_e, nilai_n);

and here :

> BigInteger.ModPow(nilai_c, nilai_d, nilai_n);

but I don't know what should I do

anyone can help me, what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "3 or more plaintexts"? Do you mean 3 or more characters in the plaintext? You might want to add some comments explaining what each of the variables in your code represent.

Comment: yes, if input is 3 digit or more, the result will false. i think because value oversize than varible. I also did fast modular exponentiation like this : public BigInteger FastModExpo(ulong a, ulong b, ulong c) { BigInteger tes = 1,x=a,e=b,m=c; x = x % m; while (e > 0) { if (e % 2 == 1) { tes = (tes * x) % m; e -= 1; } x = (x * x) % m; e /= 2; } return tes; } but still wrong

Comment: I have a feeling that your usage of `Int64` is causing a loss of precision. Try replacing all instances of `long` and `Int64` with `BigInteger`, and use `bigNum = BigInteger.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)` to convert a string `str` to a BigInteger `bigNum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer,
the problem is because plaintext value greater than N value, like this link : 
https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jpopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html

that link said :

> Break your message into small chunks so that the "Msg" codes are not
>   larger than N